# HornetQ message splitter

Tags: jms, hornetq

I'm new to JMS and HornetQ.
I'm wondering if there is a way to implement Message Translator Pattern using HornetQ to split data from a message in a set of smaller data and send them. I explored Bridge and Divert solutions but I can't get how to do it using `org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.Transformer` and `org.hornetq.core.server.ServerMessage`. Where can I find some docs about it? Am I looking in the right direction?

Comment: So do you mean to say you want split/divide the data and send to same queue or each chunk to different queue?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad I want to read the JMS message body chunk it line by line and send every line to a queue (or to another queue, it could depend about the line content).

Comment: @KarthikPrasad I'd like to do routing with apache camel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short no(I've no Idea on camel). You cannot modify the jms body once sent until its consumed by a client(body is immutable). However you can change message headers and message properties. The `org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.Transformer` interface is used for modifying the headers/properties. Hence you are left with two options.

1. Consume the message, chunk the message based on your algorithem and send to other queues or put back to the queue(but be careful to avoid loop, by having suitable selector).
2. Other approach is chunk the message then send with message property to differentiate the message. And use the diverter with filter based on the message property(you can use exclusive/non exclusive strategy to send only/send copy of message to the other queue.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where can I find some docs about using Transformers to consume chunk and send messages? Can you suggest something to start with?

Comment: You can go throw the HornetQ documentation and on extracting hornetq zip you can find example directory where you can find maven  sample project for each concepts. in this case you can examples/jms/divert project. If you need both explanation and code you can refer book "hornetq messaging developer's guide"